# MATLAB display a link to workspace elements

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to improve the readability of my outputs. In order to avoid displaying a lot of data, it would be nice to display links that point to specific elements in the workspace (i.e. a variable, a table, a figure, etc.).

Here is a picture to illustrate the idea:

[image]

Maybe we can use the `disp` function, as I know it allows the generation of hyperlinks to a webpage or a file stored in the computer.

Is this possible in MATLAB?

Comment: "I'm trying to improve the readability of my outputs" - maybe I'm just old fashioned but why isn't `fprintf()` and a little bit of programming effort on your part good enough?

Comment: @IKavanagh Thanks for your suggestion, but I want the element to be open inside the MATLAB window. I know I could create a file with the ouput, save it, then create an hyperlink, but that's not the idea...

Comment: @mat `fprintf(1, ...)` will print to the MATLAB command window. Personally I just never use the MATLAB GUI, thats what I was getting at.

Comment: @IKavanagh I don't want the element to be printed to the command window. Imagine if I have a 100x100 table? I'm not using GUI neither, I just want the variable to open in the 'view window' (don't know how it is called)

Comment: @mat - I think I have an answer for you.  Let me write an answer.

Comment: @mat I regularly work with larger matrices than that and never need to display that many values. Do you mind me asking why you need to display a 100x100 matrix in the GUI window in the picture in your question?

Comment: @rayryeng Great! Can't wait for it :D

Comment: @IKavanagh I want this feature for two reasons: 1) it improve the output readability; 2) it make it easier to find the variables, I usually have more than 100+ vars in my workspace.

Comment: @rayryeng It is exactly what I wanted, thank you very much!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK, so this is what I came up with.  The first thing is to use the [`openvar`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/view-edit-and-copy-variables.html) function and you specify the variable you want wrapped around in single quotations.  This will open up the variable in the Variable Editor (the image that is pictured in your snapshot).

Now, you can also use `disp` [to allow clickable links to run MATLAB commands](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-hyperlinks-that-run-functions.html).  Using these two ideas, you would combine the `disp` linking and `openvar` to allow a clickable link to execute the `openvar` function to display your desired variable.

As such, you would basically do this assuming our variable is stored in `A`:

```
A = magic(5);
disp('<a href="matlab:openvar(''A'')">Click on me to show the matrix A</a>')
```

The `disp` statement will show you a clickable link, and the desired function to be executed only runs if you click on the link.  You can achieve this desired effect by specifying the `matlab:` keyword inside the URL in the `href` key, then after it, you write out whatever MATLAB function or statements you want to use.  In our case, we use only need to run one function, and that's `openvar`.  Make sure you specify single quotes around the variable you want inside the argument to `openvar`.  The reason why is because the argument to `disp` is a string, and if you want single quotations to be recognized, you must use a pair of single quotes.  As such, in the `disp` string, there are pairs of single quotes around the variable you want.

Here's the what I get in MATLAB.  The steps are reproduced and shown in an animated GIF:

[image]

Comment: Wow! Favorite question (answer!) hands down

Comment: @LuisMendo - Thanks! :D It was an interesting question to solve.  I learned something new today!

Comment: @rayryeng So did I! But the way you learned it was much more fun :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo - Thanks :) Gonna go one step further and make an animated GIF.

Comment: @rayryeng Hahaha. With mistyping and all! Very nice

Comment: @LuisMendo - Gotta show people I'm not perfect :D!.