# How to highlight or identify a column with a specific value in matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, identify

I would like to highlight or identify a column in a matrix with a specific value in MATLAB. Suppose I have a matrix `A = [1 0 1 1 0 1; 1 1 0 0 0 1; 1 0 1 1 0 1; 0 1 1 0 0 1]`.

The result of the above matrix is a 5th column, as it contains all zeroes. I am also wondering if I could highlight the resulting column for identification. Please help me. I have a very large matrix to work on applying this principle.

Comment: What do you mean by highlighting?

Comment: Maybe you want to use `spy` to plot the locations of nonzero elements in a matrix. In this plot you could add some kind of highlight. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @Wauzl 
May be what you are saying is what I want. But I do not know anything about `spy` and its use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Highlighting with red (stderr)

Just for proof of concept, you *could* highlight some of your data in the command window, although I wouldn't suggest actually doing this. Consider the following code:

```
A=randi(10,8);
%ind = find(all(A==0,1),1) %for actual data
ind = 5; %manual choice for demonstration

for k=1:size(A,1)
    fprintf('%5d   ',A(k,1:ind-1));
    fprintf(2,'%5d   ',A(k,ind));
    fprintf('%5d   ',A(k,ind+1:end));
    fprintf('\n');
end
```

First we create a dummy matrix for demonstration purposes, and select column `ind` to highlight. Then we go along from line to line in `A`, we use `fprintf(...)` to write the non-highlighted values with a given format, then use `fprintf(2,...)` to write to stderr **in red**, then write the rest of the line, then newline. Note that for some reason `fprintf(2,...)` will not highlight the final character, I guess because usually this is `\n` and nobody noticed that highlighting is missing there.

Also, you can play around with the formats inside `fprintf` to suit your needs. If you need to print floating points, something like `'%10.8f'` might work. Or `'%g'`. The main point is to have a fixed width+precision for your print in order to get pretty columns.

For the sake of completeness, you can make it even a bit more messy to treat multiple highlightable columns:

```
A=randi(10,8);
%ind = find(all(A==0,1)) %for actual data
ind=[5 2];

fprintf('A = \n\n');
for k1=1:size(A,1)
    for k2=1:size(A,2)
        if ismember(k2,ind)
            fprintf(2,'%5d   ',A(k1,k2));
        else
            fprintf('%5d   ',A(k1,k2));
        end
    end
    fprintf('\n');
end
fprintf('\n');
```

I also added some extra printouts to make it prettier. Result:
[image: red highlight]

### Highlighting with blue (links)

As an afterthought, after some discussion with [Luis Mendo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32733511/how-to-highlight-or-identify-a-column-with-a-specific-value-in-matrix#comment53315622_32737124), I decided that it's worth overdoing a bit while we're at it. You can turn your numbers into blue-and-underlined hyperlinks, making use of the built-in parsing of the `<a href="URL">link</a>` HTML tag implemented both in `disp` and in `fprintf`. Here's the corresponding code:

```
A=randi(10,8);
ind=[5 2];

fieldlen=5; %width of output fields, i.e. 5 in '%5d'

fprintf('A = \n\n');
for k1=1:size(A,1)
    for k2=1:size(A,2)
        if ismember(k2,ind)
            fprintf([repmat(' ',1,fieldlen-length(num2str(A(k1,k2)))) '<a href="matlab:">%d</a>   '],A(k1,k2));
        else
            fprintf('%5d   ',A(k1,k2));
        end
    end
    fprintf('\n');
end
fprintf('\n');
```

This will turn the elements of the highlighted column(s) into strings of the form `'<a href="matlab:">3</a>'` for an example value of 3.

Another trick here is that hyperlinks starting with `matlab:` are parsed as proper matlab commands, which are activated when you click the link. You can try it by typing `disp('<a href="matlab:help help">link</a>')` in your command window. By setting `<a href="matlab:">...</a>` we make sure that nothing happens when someone clicks on the now-link-valued highlighted numbers.

And on a technical note: we only want to include the actual number in the links (and not the preceding spaces), so we have to manually check the length of the string we are about to print (using `length(num2str(A(k1,k2)))`) and manually include the rest of the spaces before the number. This is done via the parameter `fieldlen` which I set at the beginning: this specifies the total width of each printing field, i.e. if we originally had `fprintf('%5d',...)` then we need to set `fieldlen=5;` for the same effect. Result:
[image]

Comment: @StewieGriffin sorry for the extra work, I just realized that it would be fun enough to hack up:) Thanks!

Comment: Nice approach. I was typing a similar one that makes the selected column(s) boldface

Comment: @StewieGriffin@LuisMendo@AndrasDeak Great! +1! I was wondering if we also could name these identified column indices along with color coding. Like first column as 'a', second column as 'b' and so on...

Answer (score 4):

How about combining [`find`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) and [`all`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/all.html) to get the column index of the all-zero column [like this](https://ideone.com/5QDuAJ)?

```
A = [1 0 1 1 0 1; 1 1 0 0 0 1; 1 0 1 1 0 1; 0 1 1 0 0 1];
 
ind = find(all(A==0,1))
ind = 
    5
```

The second input argument to `all` is to specify that it's along the first dimension, i.e. rows. It's not really necessary here, but I find that it's a good practice as you're always sure it's the right dimension. This is especially important if there are scenarios where you might get a 1xn vector instead of mxn.

## Create a colored matrix:

This is a hack, and I don't necessarily recommend it, but if you really want to do this in MATLAB, this is an alternative. Also, I think you might learn quite a lot about MATLAB when doing this, so it might be worth the time.

You can create a colored plot with all values `1` except those in column 5 that will be `0` (or the other way around, doesn't matter) using [`imagesc`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html). This will give a plot with only two colors, one for those values that are `1`, and one for those that are `0`. You can select which colors you want with [`colormap`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html). Then you [create a mesh](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) to determine the location of all the values you want to show, convert the matrix to strings using [`num2str`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html), and combine it all. You need to experiment some to get the correct locations, as you probably want less padding between the rows than the columns. You can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21215352/matlab-confusion-matrix/21215772#21215772) as a guide. In the end, [remove the axes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16399667/2338750). It should be fairly simple to adapt if you read and try to understand each line of the referenced answer.

## The simple approach:

I have a very large matrix...". Such matrices are often not a good idea to include in a report. However, if you really want to, I actually suggest you copy paste it from the [variable explorer](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/view-edit-and-copy-variables.html) and into MS Excel (or use [`xlswrite`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html) if you're doing this more than once). Since you know which column you want to color, it should be fairly simple to click the "color button".

Comment: Wow. Such a quick response. Thanks a lot Stewie. This is exactly what I wanted. And by highlighting, I mean to add color for easy identification.

Answer (score 4):

The following displays the matrix **in the command window** with the matching columns in **boldface**. There may be **several matching columns**, and **arbitrary column values** can be matched.

```
A = [1 0 1 0 0 1; 1 1 0 1 0 1; 1 0 1 0 0 1; 0 1 1 1 0 1]; %// matrix
c = [0;1;0;1]; %// column to be matched
nn = find(all(bsxfun(@eq, A, c),1)); %// indices of matching columns
s = cellstr(num2str(A)); %// cell array of strings, one for each row; all same length
for n = nn %// for each matching column, with index n
    s = regexprep(s, '\S+', '<strong>$0</strong>', n); %// make bold n-th value of each cell
end
s = vertcat(s{:}); %// convert back into a char array; all strings have the same length
disp(s); %// display
```

The result in this example is

[image]

Comment: Well, one thing is for sure... My answer should not be the accepted one =) +1!

Comment: Although it seems messier, leaving stderr alone is always a good idea:) I vote for this one.

Comment: On the other hand, red stands out more than boldface does (+1 already)

Comment: I can also imagine a solution based on `disp` interpreting the `<a href=...` tag, turning numbers into nice blue underlined boldface links:D

Comment: @AndrasDeak Yes... but what would be the target of those links? Any suggestion?

Comment: `disp('<a href="matlab:">asdf</a>')` seems to issue an empty matlab command, so it might be relatively safe:) Go ahead if you feel like typing it up.

Comment: It was your idea. Better include it in your answer?

Comment: Now that I think about it: instead of an empty link, perhaps it would make sense to add an `openvar` command to see that variable in the variable browser? Like rayryeng did [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32572751/matlab-display-a-link-to-workspace-elements)

Comment: As the aim is only highlighting, adding a feature to the link would make it counter-productive, I would think.

Comment: @Azhar, plainly because it was not intended to be used for highlighting. In a proper programming language and system environment stderr can be treated quite differently, for instance you could end up with your unhighlighted values and the highlighted ones in two separate files. That would be bad. Now, I don't believe anything like this would happen in matlab, but it definitely counts as abuse to use stderr for such a purpose.

Comment: @AndrasDeak _it definitely counts as abuse_: we've got to make good use of this in code golf!!

Comment: @LuisMendo that would have to be a very tricky golfing question, fprintf is not that concise I'm afraid. But let me know if you get to use it:D